# Role Fuzzy Search through FBA in Share Point 2010

Tags: sharepoint, fba

I had implements two classes ,RoleProvider and the MembershipProvider.
But,I can not search the roles by Fuzzy Search.I creaded three groups in ad(g1,g2,g3).
When i just type g in the PeoplePicker,can not find anything,but type fullname g1,it works.